Подскажите, как математически реализовать
Имеется машинка, которая находится на координатах x1, y1. При этом ее курс задается переменной heading. (от -pi до pi) Имеется точка x2, y2, к которой эту машинку надо развернуть лицом. Надо посчитать target_heading курс, который нужно принять машинке, чтобы повернуться к точке. И также надо посчитать heading_diff, насколько машинке нужно довернуть, чтобы принять нужный курс. Хочу реализовать это на питоне. Пара примеров:
*Исходные данные*
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
heading = pi / 2
x2 = 1
y2 = 1
*Результат выполнения*
target_heading = pi / 4
heading_diff = -pi / 4


*Исходные данные*
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
heading = 3 * pi / 4
x2 = -1
y2 = -1
*Результат выполнения*
target_heading = -3 * pi / 4
heading_diff = pi / 2


math.atan2.
